# Query to check number of records created in a month.

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table creates a new record with timestamp daily when an integration is successful. I am trying to create a query that would check (preferably automated) the number of days in a month vs number of records in the table within a time frame.

For example, January has 31 days, so i would like to know how many days in january my process was not successful. If the number of records is less than 31, than i know the job failed 31 - x times.

I tried the following but was not getting very far:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CompleteDate)
FROM table
WHERE CompleteDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'
```

Every 7 days the system executes the job twice, so i get two records on the same day, but i am trying to determine the number of days that nothing happened (failures), so i assume some truncation of the date field is needed?!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a calendar/date table as the main source of dates in the range and left join with that and count the number of null values.

In absence of a proper date table you can generate a range of dates using a number sequence like the one found in the `master..spt_values` table:

```
select count(*) failed 
from (
     select dateadd(day, number, '2015-01-01') date 
     from master..spt_values where type='P' and number < 365
) a
left join your_table b on a.date = b.CompleteDate
where b.CompleteDate is null
and a.date BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9339d/1) (with count grouped by month)

Comment: This is my prefered solution over the other two because it is closer to what I would do and because it is more flexible (you can easily find which distinct days failed and you can control the time span without being limited to one month).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, t.d, dateadd(month, 1, t.d)) - COUNT(DISTINCT CompleteDate)
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(YEAR(CompleteDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(CompleteDate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + 
                    '01') t(d)
GROUP BY t.d
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6a35/2)

**Explanation:**

1. The value `CROSS APPLY`-ied, i.e. `t.d`, is the ANSI string of the first day of the month of `CompleteDate`, e.g. `'20150101'` for 12/01/2015, or 18/01/2015.
2. `DATEDIFF` uses the above mentioned value, i.e. `t.d`, in order to calculate the number of days of the month that `CompleteDate` belongs to.
3. `GROUP BY` essentially groups by (Year, Month), hence `COUNT(DISTINCT CompleteDate)` returns the number of distinct records per month.
4. The values returned by the query are the differences of [2] - [1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6a35/2), i.e. the number of failures per month, for each (Year, Month) of your initial data.

If you want to query a *specific* Year, Month then just simply add a `WHERE` clause to the above:

`WHERE YEAR(CompleteDate) = 2015 AND MONTH(CompleteDate) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `Integers` table*. This query will pull all dates where no record is found in the target table:

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '01/01/2013',
        @EndDate datetime = '12/31/2013'

;with d as  (
    select *, date = dateadd(d, i - 1 , @StartDate) 
    from dbo.Integers
    where i <= datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
)
select d.date 
from d
where not exists (
    select 1 from <target> t 
    where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.<timestamp>), 0) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, d.date), 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Between is not safe here

```
SELECT 31 - count(distinct(convert(date, CompleteDate)))
FROM table
WHERE CompleteDate >= '01/01/2015' AND CompleteDate < '02/01/2015'
```